# Memory Leak in NSObject+JSONSerializableSupport

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

while removing the runtime memory leaks in my iPad application , I came across this strange memory leak in NSObject+JSONSerializableSupport class in the following method

```
+ (id) deserializeJSON:(id)jsonObject {
id result = nil;
if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    //JSON array
    result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id childObject in jsonObject) {
        [result addObject:[self deserializeJSON:childObject]];
    }
}
else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    //JSON object
    //this assumes we are dealing with JSON in the form rails provides:
    // {className : { property1 : value, property2 : {class2Name : {property 3 : value }}}}
    NSString *objectName = [[(NSDictionary *)jsonObject allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];

    Class objectClass = NSClassFromString([objectName toClassName]);
    if (objectClass != nil) {
        //classname matches, instantiate a new instance of the class and set it as the current parent object
        result = [[[objectClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *properties = (NSDictionary *)[[(NSDictionary *)jsonObject allValues] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDictionary *objectPropertyNames = [objectClass propertyNamesAndTypes];

    for (NSString *property in [properties allKeys]) {
        NSString *propertyCamalized = [[self convertProperty:property andClassName:objectName] camelize];
        if ([[objectPropertyNames allKeys]containsObject:propertyCamalized]) {
            Class propertyClass = [self propertyClass:[objectPropertyNames objectForKey:propertyCamalized]];
            [result setValue:[self deserializeJSON:[propertyClass deserialize:[properties objectForKey:property]]] forKey:propertyCamalized];
        }
    }
}
else {
    //JSON value
    result = jsonObject;
}
return result;
```

}

I am getting the memory leak on this line

```
[result setValue:[self deserializeJSON:[propertyClass deserialize:[properties objectForKey:property]]] forKey:propertyCamalized];
```

Please suggest a solution or tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: As the return value seems to be autoreleased, the only thing i can see  is to change setValue:forkey: to setObject:forkey:. Might be also that  `+deserialize:` returns retained object.

Comment: @A-Live:Doing setObject doesnt work, the app crashes.

Comment: Its not obvious to me either. Why don't you switch to ARC and make your life easier (and make this probably disappear).

Comment: Have you run Analyzer on the code?